# make a script with Javascript and/or PhP to post tags in a comment section on a specific website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm thinking to make a script which can tag(announce) people on a website I browse daily. The sad thing that website has is that it doesn't provide you a button or a much simple solution to tag people you have in a list( that list with people nicknames are in a `txt` file saved in my computer) and so, you have to do it manually by `copy` them from list and then `paste` it on comment section of that website.

[image: Here's how the comment section looks]

And to make your life more harder, The website allows you to tag only 3 people per comment. That means, if I have in my tag list 99 people, I must copy-paste 3 tags and hit the Post button for 33x times...

I am motivated to try making a script for that, which will automatically :

1) `copy` 3 poeple from my file txt, in ascending order;

2) automatically set the focus on website's comment section;

3) `paste` the 3 people in the website's comment section ;

4) automatically hit the Post button ;

5) repeat all 4 previous steps.

My main question for you : Is it possible to do such script only with Javascript and/or Php ? If the answer is NO, please suggest me with what program language I can do that.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Presumably, the site has restricted tagging to 3 people per comment for a reason. What are the Terms and Conditions of the site?

Comment: I would have a look at [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp) which is an extension that can probably do what you want it to do.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but before you do this (which would take a lot of time and effort), check if the site has an API for things like this. Does the site have an API?

Comment: PS: Make sure the site is okay with bots, as this is pretty much what this is.

Comment: Short answer: technically, probably. Assuming you're not violating ToU or anything shady, that is. It's likely the service you're trying to apply this to will throttle you, if you try to do this. If this usage is permissible, look for mention of an API with endpoints corresponding to the actions you take on the page.

Comment: @Andy G is not really a restriction. You can tag more than 3 people in comments but it doesn't announce the rest of people you tag from 4th up. Terms and condition of that sites forbids  spamming bots , but this script i am about to create is not meant to do spam, just regular tag.

Comment: @DibDibs no, it doesn't have. Sadly..

Comment: Be cautious, spam can mean mass automated communication, not necessarily with the addition of advertisement, etc

Comment: No infringement is done. This is how the site allows you to tag more than 3 people. All this time I did it manually along with how other people did and nothing happened. Now I want to put "someone" else in my place, to do that. Again, is not meant to be advertising or spam, just regular tag, sticked to website rules. And don't worry, the site has protection against spam by disabling your privilage to post comments if you post more than 50 comments in that day.